# google adwords in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-ads-api

I have added plugin of google adwords in my PhoneGap  application. what should i do to see that plugin is  working as i am new to the PhoneGap .how and where will i see the changes in my application after adding that plugin to my application.. can i see any logo of adwords or anything .. please help  [i tried  this](https://github.com/Postmedia-Digital/cordova-google-adwords)
this is d code in plugin

```
public class CordovaGoogleAdWords extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray inputs, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
      //PluginResult result = null;
      //callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
      if(action.equals("track")) {
        this.track(inputs, callbackContext);
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    private void track(JSONArray inputs, CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        try {
            AdWordsConversionReporter.reportWithConversionId(
              this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
              inputs.getJSONObject(0).getString("conversionId"),
              inputs.getJSONObject(0).getString("label"),
              inputs.getJSONObject(0).getString("value"),  // The value of your conversion; can be modified to a transaction-specific value.
              Boolean.parseBoolean(inputs.getJSONObject(0).getString("repeatable"))
            );

            callbackContext.success();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Cordova Plugin Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            callbackContext.error("Unable to send tracking data");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For mobile ads use AdMob. You can use an existing plugin for phonegap/cordova: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova:

For a cordova / phonegap CLI project, use one of this command line instructions:

```
cordova plugin add com.admob.google
phonegap local plugin add com.admob.google
```

If you use Phonegap build, place the following tag in your `config.xml` file:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.google" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

Then in your javascript code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
    tappxIdiOs:           "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-iOS-IIII",            // Optional
    tappxIdAndroid:       "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-Android-AAAA",        // Optional
    tappxShare:           0.5                                        // Optional
  });

  // Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
  admob.createBannerView();

  // Request interstitial (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true)
  admob.requestInterstitial();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```